# Is this Hilbert space construction legal?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

Let $X=\ell^2=\{(\xi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\, | \, \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|\xi_i|^2<\infty\}$ be the real Hilbert space of square-summable sequences, and for every $j\in\mathbb{N}$ set
$$ X_j=\{(\xi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in X\, | \, \forall i\neq j, \xi_i=0\}.$$
It follows that $(X_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ are closed mutually orthogonal vector subspaces of $X$, and hence they are also real Hilbert spaces in their own right using the subspace topology inherited from $\ell^2$ (same norm, inner product, etc). Now, consider the "direct sum" of the $X_i$s: $(\hat{X}, \langle\cdot\, |\, \cdot \rangle)$ where

$$\hat{X}=\{ (x_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \in \times_{j\in\mathbb{N}}X_j \, | \,\|(x_j)_{j\in J}\|^2_{\hat{X}}= \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \|x_j\|^2_{\ell^2} < +\infty\}.\tag{1}$$
and
$$\langle (x_j)_{j\in J} \, | (y_j)_{j\in J} \rangle = \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \langle x_j \, | \, y_j\rangle_{\ell_2}.\tag{2}$$

> Is $(\hat{X}, \langle\cdot\, |\, \cdot \rangle)$ a valid real Hilbert space?

My colleague claims that it is not: The elements of $\hat{X}$ are a countable product of countable sequences, so in a sense it is impossible to sum them formally. Essentially they're saying that we can not append a sequence onto another sequence countably many times as done in (1). However, I have seen this direct sum construction in several books, and proofs showing it is a valid Hilbert space do not rely on the structure of the underlying $X_i$'s at all (other than the fact that they are real Hilbert spaces to start with). What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand the objection.  Each element of $\hat{X}$ is simply a sequence of elements; I don't know where the "product of sequences" idea came from.  And it is perfectly easy to sum two sequences: pointwise.  I don't understand what you mean by "append" in reference to (1).

Comment: @NateEldredge e.g. appending $x_1\in\ell^2$ and $x_2\in\ell^2$ would be $(x_1,x_2)$. They take issue with doing this countably many times.

Comment: But that's precisely what a countable Cartesian product of sets **is**!  Are they doubting that countable Cartesian products exist?  That's silly.  I mean, you do need the axiom of (countable) choice to prove that they do, but you need it to do pretty much anything in analysis.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think it's rather silly as well. Thanks for the comment, I thought this construction was fine but I guess their doubts made me ask for third opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have a typo and want to have

$$\hat X = \{(x_j) \mid \sum_j \lVert x_j \rVert^2_{\ell^2} < \infty \}.$$
Then $\hat X$ is a Hilbert space. Your construction works for **any** collection of Hilbert spaces $X_j$, not only for the subspaces $X_j \subset \ell^2$ defined in your question.

See for example section "Direct sums" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Direct_sums.

Note that if you define
$$\tilde X  = \{(x_j) \mid \sum_j \lVert x_j \rVert_{\ell^2} < \infty \},$$
then $\tilde X \subset \hat X$, thus your definition
$$\langle (x_j), (y_j) \rangle = \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \langle x_j , y_j\rangle_{\ell_2}$$
defines an inner product on $\tilde X$. However, $\tilde X$ is not a Hilbert space  - it lacks completeness.

By the way, in your example the $X_j$ are one-dimensional subpaces of $\ell^2$ and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Thus $\hat X$ is nothing else than a copy of $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo! Squares were supposed to be included in the norm, oops. This was also my impression -- the direct sum **always** yields a valid Hilbert space. My colleague takes issue with this construction though, since there is an uncountable number of items in each element of $\hat{X}$ and hence they claim it is not formally summable.

Comment: @Zim Your colleague is wrong. It does not matter what the elements of $X_j$ look like, we only need to know that they have a norm. By the way, the elements of $\hat X$ do not have uncountably many entries. The $(x_j)$ are systems of real numbers indexed by $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ which is a countable set. Moreover, each $x_j \in X_j$ has at most one non-zero entry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts: The norm you are considering in (1) is the $\ell_1$ norm and doesn’t coincide with the norm induced by the product in (2), which is the $\ell_2$ norm.
Also direct sums of infinitely many vector space are usually defined by taking sums of finitely many components.
Besides that your construction works.